# Parameter 0 of constructor in Service required a bean of Repository type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I keep getting this error message:

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.projectName.Service.UserService required a bean of type 'com.projectName.Repositories.AppUserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.projectName.Repositories.AppUserRepository' in your configuration.

those are my classes

```
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {
    AppUser findByUsername(String username);
    Optional<AppUser> findById(Long id);
}
public interface IUserService {
    AccountDto saveUser(AccountDto newUser) throws ParseException;
    AppRole saveRole(AppRole role);
    void addRoleToUser(String username, String roleName);
    EmployeeInfoDto getUser(String username);
    AppUser getUserApp(String username);
}
```

@Service @RequiredArgsConstructor @Transactional @Slf4j
public class UserService implements IUserService, UserDetailsService {

```
private final AppUserRepository userRepository;
private final AppRoleRepository roleRepository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private ModelMapper modelMapper;
private final AppUserModelAssembler assembler;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    AppUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if(user==null){
        
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User is not found in database");
    }
    else {
        
    }
    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<>();
    user.getRoles().forEach(role->{authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));});

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),authorities);
}
@Override
public AccountDto saveUser(AccountDto newUser) throws ParseException {
    
    AppUser usernameAlreadyExist=userRepository.findByUsername(newUser.getUsername());
    if(usernameAlreadyExist== null)
    {
        AppRole role=roleRepository.findByName("employee");
        newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newUser.getPassword()));
        newUser.getRoles().add(role);
        userRepository.save(assembler.convertToAppUserEntity(newUser));
        return newUser;
    }
    else return null;
}
@Override
public void deleteUser(String username){
    
    AppUser user=userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    userRepository.deleteById(user.getId());
    log.info("obrisala sam korisnika");
}
@Override
public boolean changePassword(String username, UserChangePasswordDto passwordDto){
    AppUser user=userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    String encodedOldPass=passwordEncoder.encode(passwordDto.getOldPassword());
    boolean isPasswordCorrect=passwordEncoder.matches(passwordDto.getOldPassword(),user.getPassword());
    if(isPasswordCorrect)
    {
       
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(passwordDto.getNewPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
public EmployeeInfoDto updateProfile(String username, EmployeeInfoDto userDto){
    AppUser user=userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    user.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(userDto.getLastName());
    user.setPlaceOfWork(userDto.getPlaceOfWork());
    user.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    return assembler.toModel(userRepository.save(user));
}
@Override
public AppRole saveRole(AppRole role) {
    return roleRepository.save(role);
}

@Override
public void addRoleToUser(String username, String roleName) {
    AppUser user=userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    AppRole role=roleRepository.findByName(roleName);
    user.getRoles().add(role);
}

@Override
public EmployeeInfoDto getUser(String username) {
    return assembler.toModel(userRepository.findByUsername(username));
}
public AppUser getUserApp(String username) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}
```

}

Comment: What package is your @SpringBootApplication annotated entry point class?

Comment: i  found this solution on internet, but it wasnt working also...
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: Make sure your main class is in a package that is a parent of both the service package and a repository package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your interface `AppUserRepository` with `@Repository` annotation. It allows Spring to create a bean your are missing.

Comment: I tried that, but i got the same error again

Comment: Like @Strelok said, make sure your repositories and services are in the same package as your class with main method or below in the project tree. Otherwise you should annotate your main class with 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository_package")